# How do I make my wcf services available for particular user?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-3.5

I'm using CustomMembershipProvider to validate the user for my WCF service. User will get a prompt for his credentials once he access the service.

Note: I thought I could get the username and identify the user. But how to pass variable from CustomMembershipProvider to my wcf service file?

**Custom Membership Provider Code**

Here is the code that I'm validating!

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        int authenticatedId = SecurityManager.Authenticate(username, password);
        if (authenticatedId != -1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**Here is my Basic Authentication Host Factory**

This will call my CustomMembershipProvider to replace the default web service factory.

```
public class BasicAuthenticationHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        var serviceHost = new WebServiceHost2(serviceType, true, baseAddresses);
        serviceHost.Interceptors.Add(RequestInterceptorFactory.Create("DataWebService", new CustomMembershipProvider()));
        return serviceHost;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well I'm Using NHibernate to access the database!

Comment: How do adopt my service to specific user? If user x logs in, I want to show the data related to user x. I don't know how to pass the username to the service! Kind of like session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've executed `MembershipProvider.ValidateUser`, a valid `SecurityServiceContext` should be created and added to the incoming request.

```
internal ServiceSecurityContext Create(Credentials credentials)
{
   var authorizationPolicies = new List<iauthorizationpolicy>();
   authorizationPolicies.Add(authorizationPolicyFactory.Create(credentials));
   return new ServiceSecurityContext(authorizationPolicies.AsReadOnly());
}
```

Then you should have access to the username via `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name`

I think you're working from the article [Basic Authentication on a WCF REST Service](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/BasicAuthWCFRest.aspx). The author appears to be very responsive to questions - you might want to hit him up for some pointers! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the response. You got it I'm using WCF REST Service kit! I have some error on Credentials. I implement this code in OperationContext.